# Clicking comment flag icons at short intervals displays an error message with an inaccurate text

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, rate-limiting, popup

When you select the flag icon on a comment within 3 seconds of selecting the flag icon on a *different* comment, you still get:

> You may only attempt to flag this comment every 3 seconds

Although I never attempted to flag the comment before. A better wording would be to replace *"this"* with an *"a"*, like this:

> You may only attempt to flag a comment every 3 seconds

---

One more thing I've noticed is that **when attempting to *retract* a flag** via clicking on the flag icon, if a flag icon has been clicked within 3 seconds **the same popup appears**:

> You may only attempt to flag this comment every 3 seconds

So yet a better wording might be to simply use the existing message used for flagging posts:

> You may only load the flag dialog every 3 seconds.

Or the *"flag dialog"* can also be *"comment flag dialog"* if necessary.

Comment: Maybe it's because this is a prvalue?